# Java generic notation, <E> Set <E>

Tags: java, generics

The following Java code is used to create a set in Java:

```
    Set<String> fromUi = Set.of("val1", "val2", "val3", "val4");
```

Which in term calls this code:

```
static <E> Set<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4) {
        return new ImmutableCollections.SetN<>(e1, e2, e3, e4);
    }
```

What does the "double" use of the type parameter mean? i.e can we not just say `Set<E>` instead of `<E> Set<E>`?

Comment: Read [generic methods in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html); `<E>` is a generic type declaration, `Set<E>` is a return type of the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can we not just say `Set<E>` instead of `<E> Set<E>`?

No, because then the type variable `E` wouldn't be declared.

This isn't a "double" use:

- The first `<E>` is the type variable declaration
- The second `<E>` is part of the type of the `Set<E>` which is the return type of the method: it's a `Set` whose elements are of type `E`, and to which `E`s can be added.

Declaring one or more type variables on a method makes the method a [*generic method*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4). Instance methods can access type variables from the surrounding class, and can declare their own additional ones if needed; static methods cannot access type variables from the surrounding class, and so must always declare their own.

```
// Generic class, E is accessible in instance methods/initializers/constructors.
class MyClass<E> {
  // Non-generic method, uses the E from the class.
  Set<E> someSet() { ... } 

  // Generic method, declares its own type variable.
  <M> Set<M> someSet1() { ... } 

  // Generic method, declares its own type variable which hides
  // the E on the class (bad idea).
  <E> Set<E> someSet2() { ... } 

  // Generic method, must declare its own type variable.
  static <E> Set<E> someStaticSet() { ... } 
}

// Non-generic classes can declare generic methods.
class MyClass {
  // Generic method, declares its own type variable.
  <M> Set<M> someSet1() { ... } 

  // Generic method, must declare its own type variable.
  static <E> Set<E> someStaticSet() { ... } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
static <E> Set<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4) {
```

You can read it as: whatever 'E' is (for any type 'E'), pass 4 parameters of this type and get a Set of this type as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is `static`. It won't be able to access type variables declared from its class, hence it needs to declare its own `<type>` declaration.
So its not double declaration.

```
The first <E> is where static method declares which type it uses
The second with Set<E> to specify the type of elements in a Set.
```

you won't need to use this kind of declaration if your non static method uses same generic `<type>` declared by class.